# Recoding hour-minutes to half-hour categories

Tags: r

I have a vector of time as strings like this:

```
time_hour <- c("0000", "0723", "0750", "0751", "1229", "1230")
```

where the first time point is 12:00 in the night and the last is 12:30 in the afternoon. I'd like to recode this vector into half hour categories such as:

```
recoded_time <- c("2330-0000", "0700-0730", "0730-0800", "0730-0800", "1200-1230", "1200-1230")
```

where if time lands in the exact half-hour cut point, it is recoded to the previous category as in the first and last recodes of the above example.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

time_hour <- c("0000", "0723", "0750", "0751", "1229", "1230")
```

Iterate over split hour & minutes, use `dplyr`'s `case_when` to handle the standard and edge cases & combine the calculated values with single `sprintf`'s:

```
map2_chr(
  as.numeric(substr(time_hour, 1, 2)),
  substr(time_hour, 3, 4), 
  ~case_when(
    ((.x == 0) & (.y == "00")) ~ "2330-0000",
         (as.numeric(.y) > 30) ~ sprintf("%02d30-%02d00", .x, (.x+1)),
                          TRUE ~ sprintf("%02d00-%02d30", .x, .x)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution using lubridate.

```
library(lubridate)
time_hour <- c("0000", "0723", "0750", "0751", "1229", "1230")
time_hour <- strptime(time_hour,format="%H%M")-1

paste(sprintf('%02d', hour(time_hour)), 
  sprintf('%02d', floor(minute(time_hour)/30)*30), 
  '-',
  sprintf('%02d', hour(time_hour + 1800)),
  sprintf('%02d', floor(minute(time_hour+1800)/30)*30),
  sep='')
```

Output is:

```
"2330-0000" "0700-0730" "0730-0800" "0730-0800" "1200-1230" "1200-1230"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time_hour <- c("0000", "0723", "0750", "0751", "1229", "1230")

for(t in time_hour){

  hour <- as.numeric(substr(t,1,2))
  min <- substr(t,3,4)

  if(hour == 0 & min == "00"){
    out <- "2330-0000"
  }else if(as.numeric(min) > 30){
    out <- paste(sprintf("%02d",hour),"30", "-", sprintf("%02d",(hour+1)), "00", sep = "")
  }else{
    out <- paste(sprintf("%02d",hour),"00", "-", sprintf("%02d",(hour)), "30", sep = "")
  }

  print(out)

}

[1] "2330-0000"
[1] "0700-0730"
[1] "0730-0800"
[1] "0730-0800"
[1] "1200-1230"
[1] "1200-1230"
```

Comment: The OP wld prbly like data back, not printed character vectors.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you, can you please be more clear, also please edit the question in the exact output format as desired

Comment: It's not my q. But the OP obviously wants data back, not something printed to the console.